# Else If statement is invalid, possible method required?

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

Can't seem to get this Error to go away. Where the Else If statement is the If is suggesting I put an ; there while the Else is saying it is Invalid and the parenthesis above it is also highlighted in Visual Studio. Is this because I have to create a new method which includes the For loop and then add a return or something?

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       string originalinput = Console.ReadLine();
       string userinput = originalinput.ToLower();

       while (!userinput.StartsWith("filter") || !userinput.StartsWith("exit") || !userinput.StartsWith ("stop"))
       {
           DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
           FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();
           Console.WriteLine("There Are " + folderInfo.GetFiles().Length + "Which Meet The Requirement of The Search");

           for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(" " + files[index].Name + " - " + files[index].Length + " - " + files[index].LastWriteTime);

           }
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       else if(userinput == "filter")
          {

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reduce the program until the error goes away.

Comment: An `else if` must follow a `if`, not a `while`.

Comment: you can't have an else without an if

Comment: AS others have suggested your syntax isn't right. Perhaps you could explain what you are expecting the while/else to do and we can tell you the syntax or structure you should be using...

Comment: @usr I have done, using the /* */. The error still wouldn't go away

Comment: @connormcwood implement what has been mentioned in the answers below.

Comment: @connormcwood how can the error not go away if you successively comment the entire program? You gave up prematurely.

Comment: You're right, I just did the contents of the while and if statements, I never commented out the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assign `userinput` again, so you don't need a `while`, you only need to check it once. Replace your `while` with `if`.

Comment: I am trying to make it continiously look, almost as if anything within that while is a sort of command so whether it is called then there is an exceptional in the statement. Do you understand? Would an If statement still be viable for that? I was using something I coded earlier. Thanks for the reply

Comment: You could read user input in a `while()` loop and check what to do inside that loop using `if..else if`.

Comment: I compared this to the code I did earlier and yeah you're right. That is  exactly what I did. The while loop with an exit clause then an If statement for the so called special 'commands' I want. Thank you, I'll mark yours as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
while (!userinput.StartsWith("filter") || !userinput.StartsWith("exit") || !userinput.StartsWith ("stop"))
```

Have:

```
if (!userinput.StartsWith("filter") || !userinput.StartsWith("exit") || !userinput.StartsWith ("stop"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If-Else is the construct you're looking for.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

       string originalinput = Console.ReadLine();
       string userinput = originalinput.ToLower();

       if (!userinput.StartsWith("filter") || !userinput.StartsWith("exit") || !userinput.StartsWith ("stop"))
       {
           DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
           FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();
           Console.WriteLine("There Are " + folderInfo.GetFiles().Length + "Which Meet The Requirement of The Search");

           for (int index = 0; index < files.Length; index++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(" " + files[index].Name + " - " + files[index].Length + " - " + files[index].LastWriteTime);

           }
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       else if(userinput == "filter")
       {

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place `if` statement just after the `while` loop. If `while` condition gets `false`, `if` conditions will be checked.

Like this:

```
string originalinput = Console.ReadLine();
string userinput = originalinput.ToLower();

while (!userinput.StartsWith("filter") || !userinput.StartsWith("exit") || !userinput.StartsWith ("stop"))
{
   //your code
   userinput = Console.ReadLine();  //get new user input
}
//check if input is "filter"
if(userinput == "filter")
{}
else if(userinput == "exit")
{}
else if(userinput == "stop")
{}
```